# Widget change settings doesn't update after manually changing settings

Tags: android, android-widget

I am kinda new to android programming. I am trying to make a widget that turns off and on the airplane mode. I am having trouble updating the widget after I manually change the Airplane Mode in the settings. I assumed that the onUpdate function would be invoked once I go back to the Homescreen, but I am wrong. How would I solve this?

Below is my code: Main Widget

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;

public class AirplaneModeWidget extends AppWidgetProvider
{
    private static boolean state;
    private static String TAG = "APMode_WIDGET";
    public void onCreate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        Log.i(TAG,"In onCreate");
        state = isAirplaneMode(context);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.airplane_mode);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ibtn_airplane_mode, buildButtonPendingIntent(context));
        updateUI(remoteViews);
        pushWidgetUpdate(context, remoteViews); 
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) 
    {
        Log.i(TAG,"In onUpdate");
        state = isAirplaneMode(context);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.airplane_mode);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ibtn_airplane_mode, buildButtonPendingIntent(context));
        updateUI(remoteViews);
        pushWidgetUpdate(context, remoteViews);

    }

public static PendingIntent buildButtonPendingIntent(Context context) 
{

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.ps.transparenttogglewidget.intent.action.CHANGE_STATUS");
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    public static void pushWidgetUpdate(Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews) 
    {
        ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context, AirplaneModeWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, remoteViews);     
    }

    public static void updateUI(RemoteViews rview)
    {
        Log.i(TAG,"in updateUI");
        Log.i(TAG,"State is" + state);
        if(state)
        {
            rview.setImageViewResource(R.id.ibtn_airplane_mode,R.drawable.ic_hw_airplane_on);
        }
        else
        {
            rview.setImageViewResource(R.id.ibtn_airplane_mode,R.drawable.ic_hw_airplane_off);
        }
    }
    public static boolean isAirplaneMode(Context context) 
    {
        Log.i(TAG,"in isAirplaneMode");
        return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
    }
    public static void setAirplaneMode(Context context)
    {
        Log.i(TAG,"in setAirplaneMode");
        state = isAirplaneMode(context);
        Toast.makeText(context,"state :"+state,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG,"state is "+state);
        Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, state ? 0 : 1);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        intent.putExtra("state",!state);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent); 
        state = isAirplaneMode(context);
    }
}
```

This is my IntentReceiver Code

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;


    public class AirplaneModeIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        private static String TAG = "APMode_WIDGET";
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {   
            Log.i(TAG,"in onReceive");
            if(intent.getAction().equals("com.ps.transparenttogglewidget.intent.action.CHANGE_STATUS"))
            {
                AirplaneModeWidget.setAirplaneMode(context);
                RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.airplane_mode);
                remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ibtn_airplane_mode, AirplaneModeWidget.buildButtonPendingIntent(context));
                AirplaneModeWidget.updateUI(remoteViews);
                AirplaneModeWidget.pushWidgetUpdate(context, remoteViews);
            }

        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should not check Airplane mode but check Internet.

```
//check internet connection
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

and fire your task only if network is ok..
You could check Airplane mode, if there is no network and Show a toast "please turn of Airplane mode".

Hope that helps :)